# Handlebars Partial Data with Dot Notation

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, partials

In Handlebars, I need to overwrite partial data that data is scoped within a JS object.
The index.hbs file renders multiple partials with different data, but the module properties need to be scoped within the global data object. Overwriting partial attributes using dot notation fails to compile.

Index.hbs

```html
<body>
  {{> User }}
  {{> User user.name="laura" }} // fails to compile - how to overwrite? 
</body>
```

User.hbs

```html
<div>
  Name is: {{name}}
  Location is: {{location}}
</div>
```

Index.js

```js
import index from "Index.hbs";
import user_partial from "User.hbs";

data = {
  user: {
    name: "kevin", 
    location: "bar"
  }
}

Handlebars.registerPartial(user, user_partial); 
document.innerHTML = Handlebars.compile(index)(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-contexts) says that contexts are passed to the partial like `{{> myPartial myOtherContext }}` and that additional parameters are passed like `{{> myPartial parameter=favoriteNumber }}`.

Therefore, it seems you could achieve your objective by passing `user` as the context and the overrides as parameters. Your template would become:

```
{{> User user }}
{{> User user name="laura" }}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/yj0cfzmL/) for reference.

Comment: Yes, but I would ideally prefer to pass nested properties. As well, how would you handle it if a property was doubly nested, or if one property was from the first level and the second property was from the second level?

Comment: It seems a strange use-case. You are really talking about creating a new object from within your template. One may ask why you don't create the object and then pass it to your template. But if you really want to do it within the template, then I think you will need to create a custom helper.

Comment: I agree it is a strange use case; the idea is that there is a global data spec with default data for each module type, then on implementation a module can be passed overwrites. The nested properties syntax does provide a certain amount of clarity, but also I was just surprised that I couldn't find information on this documented anywhere

Comment: I have the same question with an example that may help.  You have a button module, a module that includes a series of buttons as a set, and a module that includes that button set.  This last module wants to force a property of one of the buttons - how do you set this child property from the grandparent?  eg: `{>button_set submit.text='continue'}` You can't set the context to be just the button, or the button-set fails utterly, and flattening the data does not work for modularity (or at least adds repetition)